# How to get data of last day of each month from a time-series object array Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I receive timeseries data from an API of random days like so

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "score": 23,
    "date": "2023-08-30"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "score": 62,
    "date": "2023-08-22"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "score": 82,
    "date": "2023-07-27"
  }
          .
          .
          .
]
```

How can I elegantly get the data from this series of last day of every month?

Expecting outcome like this

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "score": 23,
    "date": "2023-08-30"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "score": 82,
    "date": "2023-07-27"
  }
          .
          .
          .
]
```

Currently trying something like this

```
const getMonthlydata = (allData: Timeseries[]): Timeseries[] => {

//Loop over every item to get max date of every month and add it to return array

}
```

Edited for better format

Comment: was the `027` intentional, and/or realistic in your dataset, or should the format be consistently `YYYY-MM-DD`?

Comment: It was by mistake, you are correct date format is `YYYY-MM-DD`, I have edited it to show correct date format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say the example array you have is inside a variable called `scores`.

Essentially this works by creating an intermediary object that maps a specific month+year to the "latest" one, and then grabs the values of that object to go back to the array format you desire.

Note *technically* speaking, this doesn't guarantee the order comes out the same as it went in. You might not care. The reason is the JS spec says object keys don't have an order. *Practically* speaking in every modern browser and js runtime (like node), it actually does maintain the order.

If you *really* want to be sure you could just sort by the date field after as well. But it's pointless in practice.

When encountering multiple entries with same dates where that date is the last one in the month overall this takes the last one due to the `>=` operator. It could be made to be the first one by changing this to `>`.

Working [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKglgWwgZwgJziqBeKBvAKCijgBMAuKAOwFcEAjdIqZAYwHs0JLaGnjSAQ2DcWwDFQDmBAL4ECAGwjAWHLskrwkqDCgDaAXRxQ9zQsWJlKARgA0zYm06iATAGZ7FqEJGUARC4ADO4AtIEAHCFBfp5QMrHmFlZQLrGOaqIAbKkO3sKiAcFuYZEuLjHM8Wa5yR65TlyU4TlePgVBoYEA7FFdFcRVBvIcVMgqCoJjAPIAZgCy7FTAABYAyhnIxlP0AFYQrMAAdABuggo0KAAUzA0oh1ykNKwQADwASvucpC9jEpK2sEQKHQmGQAD4wdcvJcANYQEAQUhaCCrEEoAGsGhoLhLZGo3TIACUODB%20FyxBGYygmOxECWABF8sYqBAAO5QRkiS40nHAPFo5CHNqE8nUxZUnl04AAaXhxgABgASPCShn5Q6SZQAMRoCgUAE0III0JdCTIQsrVcBORANcoFktlqaZPLRZSVBAAB5wMZwKQAUSWaBAxjhCKRQPxoL0VtlICGXgp4o93t9Uhtxi9PuAfskgfEIFFxAA-NQ2Rz8pcs2m80GQEL8iLExZKDQqKQIDM-YjRVxgFiqGTm8RDqOw4j%20QS0omY1jeXGDJRqzn0-kixZS1aM2DcMvczb115N3OpZPQYeW1A9wG6xfKFaz%20jRXIvFUvHg31BCfYRQRKewlEOBR2EkS4JmmeZFhWdZnCJIA).

```
type Timeseries = {
  id: number
  score: number
  date: string
}

let scores: Timeseries[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    score: 23,
    date: "2023-08-30",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    score: 62,
    date: "2023-08-22",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    score: 82,
    date: "2023-07-27",
  },
]

const lastOfMonthScores = Object.values(
  scores.reduce<Record<string, Timeseries>>(
    (keyedTimeSeries, currentTimeSeries) => {
      const currentDate = new Date(currentTimeSeries.date)
      const currentKey = `${currentDate.getFullYear()}-${currentDate.getMonth()}`
      const existingEntry = keyedTimeSeries[currentKey]
      const existingDate = existingEntry
        ? new Date(existingEntry.date)
        : undefined
      return {
        ...keyedTimeSeries,
        [currentKey]: existingDate
          ? currentDate >= existingDate
            ? currentTimeSeries
            : existingEntry
          : currentTimeSeries,
      }
    },
    {},
  ),
)

console.log(lastOfMonthScores)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```js
const DATE_PATTERN = /(\d{4}-\d{2})-\d{2}/

const getMonthlydata = (allData: Timeseries[]): Timeseries[] => {
  const maximums: Record<string, Timeseries> = {}
  for (const data of allData) {
    const match = data.date.match(DATE_PATTERN)
    if (!match) {
      throw new Error(`Invalid date: ${data.date}`)
    }
    const month = match[1]
    if (!maximums[month] || maximums[month].date < data.date) {
      maximums[month] = data
    }
  }
  return Object.values(maximums)
}
```

This is dependent upon the dates being properly formatted, so using a regex lets us ensure that. This creates an object (basically a map) that holds each year/month as keys, and the maximum value for that year/month as the values. One of the nice things about ISO formatted dates (like this) is that they're sortable alphabetically, so you can simply compare the date strings directly.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAKglgWwgZwgJziqBeKBvAKCijgBMAuKAOwFcEAjdIqZAYwHs0JLaGnjSAQ2DcWwDFQDmBAL4ECHKsmBQAIgEEYAUQD6ABU3aASgDkcUAPQAKADqk8AFhkBaO3gBMMgJSv7ni-KKylCSEMAAsuxUwAAWADYgQsCC5laCcXGqwoKU8EioGCgA2gC6XrmIKOiYyKU4AHz4zEEqCIIAHoh0yJRGEBxopAA8yhKSADSwlQU1jbh4csQAZpxQVi1QSSnsS1DpmdleTcTEG23ArDHmWwB0SRA355dWGtr6hlqmXszEcLtWAEInjEjoQTidYmh2AB3agQWFaNBQtBWAAGAEkqAA3dJkTbCUQAEjwt3uMlR33BixOZyisXMwKKAEYSj8SP8gR0ughagg6TESlAAD5CqBtToIbpFPnRAV3AlQIb45LykSgtnEcXc3n8wW4LZs6nUrjAGhoKhQADy9AAVv1gDccXEaCgrFrJTzvnIFFFgshBAgwHFRHkqoVanqoEVmGCTmRKEzxmy2JxRO4AMxJ8H3SgAcncAAYM84CwAOZzpgu5rNQGQ12O-ChQdw14gpriUABsLbZOag+aL6ZL5fc7mrzDrMbZ8agmeTA1EpZ72YJecLxYLAHZnO5N+PiJPWQQIO0wJwVBs0DQLbhBMgQFRWGtylA9FCEHBUEMsewyHNGrGl4oDQcQqLgoQRPyCRbFY-qBsGlJQEE7DBjccTsJIVhcMgIHAF68g-niV5UFYXg3KwwjPFY6DIpQ14ANZUDCVBHNgjTIahNGcNRSKcF43xAA)

Comment: Good answer. We arrived at the same station :).

Comment: Was too slow on this one. :) But I decided to post it anyway, because the date parsing carries some dangers without validation of the format, and the string-comparability of ISO timestamps is a useful trick. It's true of all forms, even with offsets like `2023-09-07T12:34:56.789+05:00` or `-07:00`.

Comment: For sure. The primary difference is mine is more "loose" around the date format whereas yours is more strict. Possibly desirable or undesirable depending on the use case. I reckon yours might be milliseconds faster as well because of regex vs date instantiation and the use of plain old for loop. I'm a little obsessed with functional programming . Upvoting.